# Remove firebase data of user, if referral code is not utilized in the backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I don't want a user account entry to be created, until a referral code is utilized in the main backend.

But the authentication process does a firebase authentication first.

Will I be able to delete firebase entry of the user? Or Can firebase automatically deletes user data on a specific condition?

What other methods I could follow?

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will I be able to delete firebase entry of the user?

You can certainly write code using the Firebase Admin SDK to [delete user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) as you see fit.

> Or Can firebase automatically deletes user data on a specific condition?

Firebase never automatically deletes user accounts.  You have to either do that manually or write code to do it.

If you want to periodically delete accounts that don't have some conditions set to be valid, you could use Cloud Functions to write a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that will find a delete accounts you no longer want.

Comment: I thought of your solution and came up with a different version of events. So the plan is now to use the onunload event and start a worker process in the backend which will validate and delete such users data, using the cloud function.